# Issue with scala time constraints on leetcode

Tags: scala

The Scala code on leetcode always get a 'Compile Timeout' Error. Don't know how to deal with that.Even sometimes get luckily compiles. The submission result is still 'Time Limit Exceeded'. It not because my answer is time consuming, it fails on the simplest test case.
The problem is '135 Candy'
Here is my code.

```
object Solution {
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def candy(ratings: Array[Int]): Int = {
  candyLoop(ratings.toSeq, -1, 0,0, 0, 0)
}
@tailrec
def candyLoop(remains: Seq[Int],
            tailValue: Int,
            peekCandy:Int,
            tailCandy: Int,
            totalCandy: Int,
            toPeek: Int

           ): Int = {
if (remains.isEmpty) {
  totalCandy
} else {
        //println(s"$tailValue : $tailCandy : $totalCandy : $toPeek")
  val nextVal = remains.head
  if (nextVal > tailValue) {


    candyLoop(remains.tail,
              nextVal,
              tailCandy + 1,
              tailCandy + 1,
              totalCandy + tailCandy + 1,
              0)
  } else if (tailCandy > 1) {
    candyLoop(remains.tail, nextVal,peekCandy, 1, totalCandy + 1, toPeek + 1)
  } else {
    val boost = if(peekCandy > toPeek + 1) toPeek else toPeek + 1
    candyLoop(remains.tail, nextVal, peekCandy,1, totalCandy + boost + 1, toPeek + 1)
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: As this is working code (it presumably compiles, runs, and produces reasonable output), the question belongs over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and not here.